# My jQuery in a closure still throws an error

Tags: jquery

I have read as many of the posts on SO that deal with jQuery closures as I can find and I have tried to fashion my code to the best answers provided however, I still find that errors occur with some other 3rd party scripts.

The typical error I see is

```
 $ is not a function. (In '$(document)', '$' is undefined
```

or

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'jQuery.noConflict')
```

What I want to do is to be able to execute my jQuery **without conflicting** with other people's jQuery **regardless** of how sloppy theirs may be.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
// 'myName' is the global object for my functions
var myName = {};

// reduce potential conflicts with other scripts on the page
myName.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
var $myName = myName.jQuery;

// Create unique object and namespace for stack functions
myName.stackFunctions = {};

// Define a closure
myName.stackFunctions = (function(myNameObject) {
    // When jQuery is used it will be available as $ and jQuery but only
    // inside the closure.
    var jQuery = myName.jQuery;
    var $ = jQuery;
    var $myName = jQuery.noConflict();

$myName(document).ready(function() {
    myName.stackFunctions.move();

});

myName.stackFunctions.move = function() {

    $myName(".modal-open").css( "z-index", "99" );
    $myName( "span.prependAppend" ).prependTo( $( ".footer-copyright" ) );
    $myName( ".generateHash.hashRemove" ).remove();
    $myName( ".hashRemove" ).remove();
    $myName(".editIcon .log-in").css( "font-size", "18px" );

};

    return myNameObject;
})(myName.stackFunctions);
```

I have also tried to do it this way:

```
function myName() {
    $(".modal-open").css( "z-index", "99" );
    $( "span.prependAppend" ).prependTo( $( ".footer-copyright" ) );
    $( ".generateHash.hashRemove" ).remove();
    $( ".hashRemove" ).remove();
    $(".editIcon .log-in").css( "font-size", "18px" );
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  myName();

 });
```

Comment: jQuery's `no-conflict` is for other libraries that use `$`, not for other jQuery code.

Comment: when I remove the no-conflict it then says '$' is undefined ...

Comment: Is jQuery loaded at that point?

Comment: Yes, it is loaded before my jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think jquery is not loaded properly.Please make sure that you have loaded jquery before '$' used in code.If you already loaded jquery then please check if it is loaded synchronously or not.Remove async from your script tag (if exists).

Comment: Yes, it is loaded at the top of the page in the head like this <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="files/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: Is there something wrong with the way I am using the closure?

Comment: is your site hosted to the web?can you share the url so that I can check?

Comment: ok,please try once loading jquery from cdn..
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>